# How to compare values in the Arraylist and 2D array in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a string type arraylist: [big,small]
and a string 2D array like:

```
[[XXXXXX],[XXXBIG],[XLLAMS],[XXXXXX]]
```

How could I match the value in the 2D array and output the location of words?

---

Expected output:

```
Found big at [1,3] right
Found small at [2,5] left
```

Comment: I was thinking for a long time, such as changed array list into char and compare or trying to combine 2d array into an array, then compared it. But if I have a 20X20 char txt file, and need to search words, it gonna be a problem.

Comment: Oh, you're doing like a word-search solver?

Comment: yes,sry i did not see your comment.

Comment: You should edit your question to include that information; it's pretty unclear what you mean by "compare values in an ArrayList to a 2D array", but people will instantly understand if you say it's for word searches.